# is there anything like RightMark for Linux?

Tags: linux, profiling

[CPU RightMark](http://cpu.rightmark.org/download.shtml) is a Windows profiler for certain system dependent values like memory latency and others. Is there an equivalent system for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This is called benchmarking, not profiling.  I don't know of a golden standard hardware benchmakring tool for Linux, but you can google for specific things you want to measure and find various tools for that.

Comment: benchmarking, not profiling. Ok, what are the definitions of both?

Comment: I don't really know format definitions.  Intuitively benchmarking is usually used to measure how quickly something works and profiling is used to figure out what's the slowest part of the system.